# wsgi python error: WSGI Applications must yield bytes

Tags: apache, https, wsgi

Running Apache2 and python3 on Ubuntu. I want to configure this for a http REST api via URL: https://api.domainname.com which is being forwarded to a python program with wsgi server running on port 5000.
Installed wsgi server

```
$ sudo pip install wsgiserver
```

Created wsgi.py program

```
import wsgiserver
def my_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ['WSGIserver is running!']

server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(my_app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
server.start()
```

Ran the program

```
$python3 wsgi.py &
```

Verified the server is listening on port 5000

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

From Browser, I perform https://api.domainname.com
On the browser I get error:

```
This page isn’t working api.domainname.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I get error in my console window like this:

```
ValueError('WSGI Applications must yield bytes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wsgiserver.py", line 1394, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wsgiserver.py", line 848, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wsgiserver.py", line 2347, in respond
    raise ValueError("WSGI Applications must yield bytes")
ValueError: WSGI Applications must yield bytes
```

I am new to wsgi. I am not trying to serve a webpage but I need a call a https based REST URL from external server to go to a python program via wsgi server on port 5000 that returns some value based on the url. I am in the initial stages of testing to see if basic communication works and not able to make it work.  I dont know if my wsgi server configuration is wrong or my program. Can you advise?

Comment: What happens if you change the return value of my_app to `return [b'WSGIserver is running!']`?

Comment: Yes it worked. What is b out in bytes? If I have to return a rest based json response, should I put b there. Also will the current wsgi work or should I install wsgi_mod

Comment: In python there are `bytes` objects and there are strings (type `str`). Evidently you need to return bytes objects. You will have to find a tutorial on python or perhaps some other question here on SO to get more information on bytes objects and strings and how to go from one to the other. `'some string'` is a string literal and `b'some bytes'` is a bytes literal.

Comment: Ok great response